# JQuery Modal Dialog does not behave as in example

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, node.js, jquery-ui-dialog, express

First of all, I am new to JQuery and Web technologies overall. I have been playing with node.js/expressjs/jade.js and JQuery few weeks so far.

For some reason I just cant get modal dialog work. Following code shows button and button click shows "dialog". This dialog is just div element below button, not over button. On the top of that you cannot move button and style is not same as shown in JQuery example.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Could someone be kind and point the problem or copy-paste working example. Thanks.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Places Server</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready( function(){
            jQuery("#myButton").click( showDialog );
                //variable to reference window
                $myWindow = jQuery('#myDiv');

                //instantiate the dialog
                $myWindow.dialog({ height: 350,
                        width: 400,
                        modal: true,
                        position: 'center',
                        autoOpen:false,
                        title:'Hello World'
                        //overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'}
                        });
                }

      );
      //function to show dialog   
      var showDialog = function() {
        //if the contents have been hidden with css, you need this
        $myWindow.show(); 
        //open the dialog
        $myWindow.dialog("open");
        }

      //function to close dialog, probably called by a button in the dialog
      var closeDialog = function() {
        $myWindow.dialog("close");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>     
    <input id="myButton" name="myButton" value="Click Me" type="button"/>
    <div id="myDiv" style="display:none" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all undefined ui-draggable ui-resizable">
      <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span id="ui-dialog-title-dialog" class="ui-dialog-title">Dialog title</span></div>
      <div id="dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
        <p>I am a modal dialog</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/LPeeC/

Issue was your click event, rest you can play around with the demo,

This should help, `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    jQuery("#myButton").click(function(e){
             showDialog()

             e.preventDefault();
            });
                //variable to reference window
                $myWindow = jQuery('#myDiv');

                //instantiate the dialog
                $myWindow.dialog({ height: 350,
                        width: 400,
                        modal: true,
                        position: 'center',
                        autoOpen:false,
                        title:'Hello World'
                        //overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'}
                        });
                }

      );
      //function to show dialog   
      var showDialog = function() {
        //if the contents have been hidden with css, you need this
        $myWindow.show(); 
        //open the dialog
        $myWindow.dialog("open");

        }

      //function to close dialog, probably called by a button in the dialog
      var closeDialog = function() {
        $myWindow.dialog("close");
      }
​
```

Comment: Only difference I see is that you set e.preventDefault(); Even I add that dialog is statically places below button. I don't believe this is javascript issue. This is more like CSS or HTML issue.

Comment: @user867487 ?? ummm Brilliant! Glad you noticed the difference, okies and what have I mentioned in my post? `the way you are calling your click` anyhoo man hope this helps! take it easy, **plz** note right click on the demo and see the scripts which I have included, cheers! **Also note** I am **not** the one who downvoted you so it must be someone else, to clear out the air `:)`

Comment: Problem was missing jquery ui library.

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: @user867487 Mate - see **Replication of your Issue ==> Even  though correct scripts are there link =** http://jsfiddle.net/LRP7E/ with **Correct library** and please stop trying to prove that I helped you but its actually not useful, anyhoo above demo will prove you what I changed in my **working demo** above, Cheers